# Requests on iOS app using firebase denied: Restricted api key

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

I'm developing an iOS app with a firebase project as the backend.
In the goodle documentaiton it's specified that we should restrict our api keys - and to be more specific, to restrict my iOS api key to only the apps with a certain bundle id.

In my app i use phone login. After I've restricted the key to only my app bundle id, that stopped working with a response of 403. After i removed the bundle id from the restriction section, it started working again.

Anyone has any ideas why?

Haven't tried on a real device, this is happening on the simulator.

[image: i've added the bundle identified in lower case and in capitalized( as the one from xcode) just to be sure one of them is right, but still the same 403]

```
"Requests from this iOS client application <empty> are blocked.","domain":"global","reason":"forbidden"}],"status":"PERMISSION_DENIED","details":[{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo","reason":"API_KEY_IOS_APP_BLOCKED","domain":"googleapis.com","metadata":{"service":"identitytoolkit.googleapis.com",
```

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70284501/requests-from-referrer-empty-are-blocked) but didn't help much